# creating a pop up form that shows up when clicking a button

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a pop up form that shows up when clicking on a button. Is there like an attribute I can add to the  or  tags that can allow the "pop up" action?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS to specify a top and left position, make it static, and add a className attribute to the component. Make display none and when the button is clicked, set display to block.